# .NetCore project.json "scripts" does not run any command

Tags: build, compiler-errors, asp.net-core, project.json, post-build

I need a simple `postcompile` script to work, but i cant seem to get any script to work..

in my `project.json` i have the following:

```
"scripts": {
   "postcompile": "echo before building",
   "precompile": "echo after building"
}
```

but when i build, instead of the `echo` i get an error: `No executable found matching command "echo"`

it is the same for any other basic command like `cd`, `dir`, even `cmd`.
though `dotnet pack` works

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you do: `cmd.exe /c echo before building`?

Comment: no, cmd doesnt work as well... though dotnet pack does.

Comment: "postcompile": "cmd /c echo postcompile" work

Comment: For me, these all work find in `Visual Studio`'s build, but fails in `msbuild`, which is used by `Jenkins`.  So everything passes developer testing, and then fails in auto-ci.

Comment: @TomerW did you solve this at some point? How? In a `prepublish` script I'd like to change to a sub-directory where Angular client app sits and then run some `npm run some-build-task` from there.

Comment: @superjos My original problem was that i had an extra (unwanted) folder win7-x64, I didn't actually solve this, I just stopped using the "platform".
For matter of fact, I ended up neglecting .NET Core altogether and ported back to .NET FW.

Comment: :O thanks for your feedback. In the meantime, I discarded idea of changing directory, and ran npm from there taking advantage of its `--prefix some-sub-dir` option.